# MariaDB engine innodb status raw operations reads / s calculation

Tags: mariadb, innodb, galera

I am trying to find out possible performance issues with our galera cluster and had a look into the engine innodb status output.

Under raw operations the counter for inserted, updated, deleted and read are listed as well as a read/s but I cannot find any information about how this is calculated.

I saw this here before server restart:

```
Number of rows inserted 4071508, updated 3162114, deleted 1655661, read 25711900253
20.46 inserts/s, 0.62 updates/s, 0.46 deletes/s, 51.38 reads/s
```

and after server restart I see this here:

```
Number of rows inserted 4112209, updated 3246564, deleted 1692361, read 26696845630
60.55 inserts/s, 1.48 updates/s, 0.55 deletes/s, 103388.50 reads/s
```

so the number of reads has increased but not drastically but the reads per seconds has gone from 50 to more than 100.000 per second.

I assume that the read counter is somehow divided by the server up time but cannot find any confirmation on that.

Does anyone has insights in this?

Thanks in advance and greetings.

Comment: Quite confusing.  File a bug: jira.mariadb.org

Comment: I like to use the slowlog, with `long_query_time=1`.